# Generate HTML to show custom questions with the correct type (text, checkbox, ...) and add the required attribute properly

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have a form for a user create custom questions. For that the user needs to introduce the question (ex: Whats your phone?) and also the type of field (text, long text, checkbox, select menu, radio button). If the user selects a field of checkbox, select menu or radio button he also need to introduce the available options for the question.

In the database the questions are inserted in the questions and question_options tables like:

Questions Table:

```
id       question         type        conference_id
1          Text            text             1 
2        Checkbox         checkbox          1 
3          Radio           radio_btn        1 
4          select         select_menu       1 
5         textarea         long_text        1 
6           file             file           1
```

Registration_type_questions pivot table:

```
id registration_type_id   question_id  required
1         1                     1          1   
2         1                     2          1   
3         1                     3          0   
4         1                     4          0   
5         1                     5          0   
6         1                     6          1
```

The options are stored in the questions_options table:

```
   id   question_id   value

    1          2        check1  
    2          2        check2  
    3          3        rad1    
    4          3        rad2    
    5          4        select1
    6          4        select2
```

Then in the view I want to show properly in the view registration.blade.php the inputs (text, radio button, checkbox, select, textarea and input file) based on the type stored in the column "type" of the questions table. And also add the required attribute if the required column in the pivot table is "1".

When a question is of the type text, radio button, select, textarea or file it is working fine, the required attribute is added to the form field.

But it's not working properly with checkboxes because in the case of checkboxes if the question is of type checkbox and the question is required that should mean that the user needs to answer that question but should not mean that the user needs to check all checkboxes.

The issue is that with the function getHTMLInput() the generated html for checkboxes have required in each checkbox input and because of that the user needs to check all checkboxes:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="participant_question">Checkbox</label>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" name="participant_question[]" value="check1" class="form-check-input" required="">  
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">check1</label>
    </div> 
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" name="participant_question[]" value="check2" class="form-check-input" required="">    
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">check2</label>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" value="2" name="participant_question_id[]">
  </div>
```

Do you know how to solve that issue? When a custom question is required that should mean that the question is required so the user should select at least 1 checkbox but should not mean that the user needs to check all checkboxes.

And also do you know how to, if the custom question is required add inside each question label this "`<span class="text-primary">*</span>`"?

GetHtmlInput() in the Question model:

```
class Question extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'question', 'type', 'conference_id',
    ];

    public static $typeHasOptions = [
        'radio_btn',
        'select_menu',
        'checkbox'
    ];

    public function registration_type()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\RegistrationType', 'registration_type_questions')
            ->withPivot('required');
    }

    public function options()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\QuestionOption');
    }

    public function hasOptions()
    {
        return in_array($this->type, self::$typeHasOptions);
    }

    public function getHtmlInput($name = "", $options = "", $required = false, $class = "", $customtype = false) {

        $html = '';
        $html .= $customtype == 'select_menu' ? "<select name='participant_question' class='form-control' " . ($required ? " required" : "")
            . ">" : '';

        if (empty($options)) {
            switch ($customtype) {
                case "text":
                    $html .= " 
                    <input type='text' name='participant_question' class='form-control'" . ($required ? " required" : "")
                        . ">";
                    break;

                case "file":

                    $html .= " 
                    <input type='file' name='participant_question' class='form-control'" . ($required ? " required" : "") . ">";
                    break;

                case "long_text":
                    $html .= "
                <textarea name='participant_question' class='form-control' rows='3'" . ($required ? " required" : "") . ">"
                        . $name .
                        "</textarea>";

                    break;
            }
        } else {
            foreach ($options as $option) {
                switch ($customtype) {
                    case "checkbox":
                        $html .= " 
                <div class='form-check'>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='participant_question[]' value='" . $option->value . "' class='form-check-input'" . ($required ? " required" : "") . ">" .
                            '    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">' . $option->value . '</label>' .
                            "</div>";
                        break;
                    case "radio_btn":
                        $html .= " 
                <div class='form-check'>
                    <input type='radio' name='participant_question[]' value='" . $option->value . "' class='form-check-input'" . ($required ? " required" : "") . ">" .
                            '    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">' . $option->value . '</label>' .
                            "</div>";
                        break;
                    case "select_menu":
                        $html .= "<option value='" . $option->value . "'>" . $option->value . "</option>";
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        $html .= $customtype == 'select_menu' ? "</select>" : '';

        return $html;
    }
}
```

Then the getHtmlInput() is used like:

```
@if ($allParticipants == 0)
    @foreach($selectedRtype['questions'] as $customQuestion)
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="participant_question">{{$customQuestion->question}}</label>
            @if($customQuestion->hasOptions() && in_array($customQuestion->type, ['checkbox', 'radio_btn', 'select_menu']))
                {!! $customQuestion->getHtmlInput(
                    $customQuestion->name,
                    $customQuestion->options,
                    ($customQuestion->pivot->required == '1'),
                    'form-control',
                    $customQuestion->type)
                !!}

            @else
                {!! $customQuestion->getHtmlInput(
                    $customQuestion->name,
                    [],
                    ($customQuestion->pivot->required == '1'),
                    'form-control',
                    $customQuestion->type)
                !!}
            @endif
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="participant_question_required[]"
                   value="{{ $customQuestion->pivot->required }}">
            <input type="hidden"
                   value="{{ $customQuestion->id }}"
                   name="participant_question_id[]"/>
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Generated HTML with getHTMLInput():

```
<form method="post" action="">


  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="participant_question">Text</label>
    <input type="text" name="participant_question" class="form-control" required="">
    <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="participant_question_id[]">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="participant_question">Checkbox</label>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" name="participant_question[]" value="check1" class="form-check-input" required="">  
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">check1</label>
    </div> 
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" name="participant_question[]" value="check2" class="form-check-input" required="">    
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">check2</label>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" value="2" name="participant_question_id[]">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="participant_question">Radio</label>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="radio" name="participant_question[]" value="rad1" class="form-check-input">  
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">rad1</label>
    </div> 
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="radio" name="participant_question[]" value="rad2" class="form-check-input">   
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">rad2</label>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" value="3" name="participant_question_id[]">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="participant_question">select</label>
    <select name="participant_question" class="form-control">
      <option value="select1">select1</option>
      <option value="select2">select2</option>
    </select>

    <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" value="4" name="participant_question_id[]">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="participant_question">textarea</label>
    <textarea name="participant_question" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" value="5" name="participant_question_id[]">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="participant_question">file</label>
    <input type="file" name="participant_question" class="form-control" required="">
    <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" value="6" name="participant_question_id[]">
  </div>

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Store">
</form>
```

Also, checking this form in a HTML validator like w3c validator it appears some errors:

- The for attribute of the label element must refer to a non-hidden form control. In "Text

  The for attribute of the label element must refer to a non-hidden form control. In "Checkb"

  The for attribute of the label element must refer to a non-hidden form control. In "check1"

  The for attribute of the label element must refer to a non-hidden form control. In "check2"

  The for attribute of the label element must refer to a non-hidden form control. In "rad1

  The for attribute of the label element must refer to a non-hidden form control. In "rad2

  The for attribute of the label element must refer to a non-hidden form control. In   "select"

  The for attribute of the label element must refer to a non-hidden form control. In "textar"

  The for attribute of the label element must refer to a non-hidden form control. In "file

Comment: I mean checkboxes only have two possible states, so aren't they implicitly required

Comment: So a checkbox field should not be a required field?

Comment: @johnW, what I believe James is saying is "if a checkbox is required then it is required to be checked. So why is it something the user must check?". Unless it is an "I agree/consent" checkbox, which would be required.

Comment: Thanks, but what is necessary is to have a group of checkboxes required then the user should select at least one checkbox of the group because is a required group of checkboxes.

Answer (score 8):

It is because you have the checkbox group html inside your `foreach` loop here:

```
 foreach ($options as $option) {
                switch ($customtype) {
                    case "checkbox":
                        $html .= " 
                <div class='checkbox-group' " . ($required ? " required" : "") . ">
```

You need to think about how you would get around this maybe using a variable like `$checkboxesFound` and set it to 0 at the start of the function and when case is checkbox, increment the variable, and if `$checkboxesFound == 0` then echo the group div.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not understanding why is necessary that checkboxesFound because when is checkboxes the code for checkboxes is in "case "checkbox".

Comment: You will have to rethink the structure of this code then, I used `$checkboxesFound` as an example , so the first time you have a checkbox case, the variable will be 0, then increment it so the next time checkbox is found it will not equal 0 and you won't echo the checkbox group, sorry I'm on mobile atm

Comment: Thanks, but is not possible to have always the same structure with "checkbox-group" even if there is only 1 checkbox inside the div with the "checkbox-group" class?

Comment: Yes, you could put just 1 within the group, but I'm a tad confused on the input here, you say you want your output to have 2 checkboxes within a checkbox group? Is this every time or input dependant? What are the argument values coming into the function?

Comment: Thanks I also dont know what is the best approach for this case. For all inputs is working fine if the custom question is required  the required attribute appears on the input. But in the checkboxes case,  for a question of type checkbox with the code above all checkboxes associated to that question need to be checked because all checkbox input appear with the "required" attribute. But, if the question is of type checkbox and the question is required that should mean that the user needs to answer that question but should not mean that the user needs to select all checkboxes.

Comment: He should be able to only select 1 checkbox, required should mean that in a group of checkboxes at least 1 checkbox needs to be checked, should not mean that all checkboxes associated to a question of type checkbox needs to be all checked.

Answer (score 6):

Replace your getHtmlInput() with this

```
public function getHtmlInput($question_id, $index_position, $name = "", $options = "", $required = false, $class = "", $customtype = false) {

    //dd($name);
    $html = '';
    $html .= $customtype == 'select_menu' ? "<select name='participant_question[".$question_id."][".$index_position."]' class='form-control' " . ($required ? " required" : "")
        . ">" : '';

    if (empty($options)) {
        switch ($customtype) {
            case "text":

                $html .= " 


                <input type='text' name='participant_question[".$question_id."][".$index_position."]' class='form-control'" . ($required ? " required" : "")
                    . ">";


                break;

            case "file":

                $html .= " 


                <input type='file' name='participant_question[".$question_id."][".$index_position."]' class='form-control'" . ($required ? " required" : "") . ">";


                break;

            case "long_text":
                $html .= "

            <textarea name='participant_question[".$question_id."][".$index_position."]' class='form-control' rows='3'" . ($required ? " required" : "") . ">"
                    . $name .
                    "</textarea>";

                break;
        }
    } else {
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            switch ($customtype) {
                case "checkbox":
                    $html .= " 
            <div class='form-check'>
                <input type='checkbox' name='participant_question[".$question_id."][".$index_position."][]' value='" . $option->value . "' class='form-check-input'" . ($required ? " required" : "") . ">" .
                        '    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">' . $option->value . '</label>' .
                        "</div>";
                    break;
                case "radio_btn":
                    $html .= " 
            <div class='form-check'>
                <input type='radio' name='participant_question[".$question_id."][".$index_position."][]' value='" . $option->value . "' class='form-check-input'" . ($required ? " required" : "") . ">" .
                        '    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">' . $option->value . '</label>' .
                        "</div>";
                    break;
                case "select_menu":
                    $html .= "<option value='" . $option->value . "'>" . $option->value . "</option>";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    $html .= $customtype == 'select_menu' ? "</select>" : '';

    return $html;
}
```

and

blade code with this

```
@if ($allParticipants == 0)
{{ $index_position = 0 }}
@foreach($selectedRtype['questions'] as $customQuestion)

   {{ $question_id = [[QUESTION_ID]] }}

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="participant_question">{{$customQuestion->question}}</label>
        @if($customQuestion->hasOptions() && in_array($customQuestion->type, ['checkbox', 'radio_btn', 'select_menu']))
            {!! $customQuestion->getHtmlInput(
                $question_id,
                $index_position,
                $customQuestion->name,
                $customQuestion->options,
                ($customQuestion->pivot->required == '1'),
                'form-control',
                $customQuestion->type)
            !!}

        @else
            {!! $customQuestion->getHtmlInput(
                $question_id,
                $index_position,
                $customQuestion->name,
                [],
                ($customQuestion->pivot->required == '1'),
                'form-control',
                $customQuestion->type)
            !!}
        @endif
    </div>
    {{ $index_position = $index_position+1 }}
@endforeach
@endif
```

you need to set the name attribute same of same group options in order to work required option properly.

But in your code all options including of different option groups are sharing same name attribute.

The above code is not tested. But I hope it will work for you

Comment: Thanks, but like that if the checkbox field is required the user also need to check all checkboxes associated with that checkbox field. And also for each field is appearing a number like  "0
Text", "1
Checkbox", "...".

Comment: And with that code when form button "Store Registration" is clicked it appears an error "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'question_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `answers` (`question_id`, `participant_id`, `answer`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, 38, re, 2018-06-10 11:33:48, 2018-06-10 11:33:48))".

Comment: I have modified the code for question id. make sure you fetch the correct question id and replace with [[QUESTION_ID]]. ok

Comment: checkbox are meant to optional. 
but still get this.
you can replace the following lines

Comment: Thanks, with that code the in the generated html the name has values like 2"participant_question[2][1][]", like for example the generated html for checkbox:

Comment: "  12 <div class="form-group"><label for="participant_question">Checkbox</label><div class="form-check"> <input type="checkbox" name="participant_question[2][1][]" value="check1" class="form-check-input" required="">    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">check1</label></div> <div class="form-check"> <input type="checkbox" name="participant_question[2][1][]" value="check2" class="form-check-input" required="">    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">check2</label></div> </div>".

Comment: Why the name cant be just participant_question[]? And with that code if the checkbox field is required all checkboxes need to be checked.

Answer (score 4):

HTML5 doesn't have a solution to implement that a group of checkboxes should be required, so with some changes you could achieve it. First on your controller you will need to change it to achieve the same you are doing with your select menu.

```
// on top of your method:
$html .= $customtype == 'checkbox' ? "<div class='checkbox-group ".($required ? " required" : "")."'>" : '';
// at the bottom
$html .= $customtype == 'checkbox' ? "</div>" : '';
```

Then in your case 'checkbox' you would only need to print the options that will be inside your 'required group of checkboxs':

```
case "checkbox":
            $html .= " 
            <div class='form-check'>
                <input type='checkbox' name='participant_question[]' value='" . $option->value . "' class='form-check-input' ><label class='form-check-label' for='exampleCheck1'>" . $option->value . "</label>
            </div>";
```

This should output the following html:

```
<div class="checkbox-group required">   
  <div class="form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" name="participant_question[]" value="whatever" class="form-check-input"><label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">whatever</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" name="participant_question[]" value="whatever2" class="form-check-input"><label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">whatever2</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then  on submit, I don't know if you do it with ajax or not but I'll assume you do not, so if you add an id to your form -> `id="questionForm"`

```
$('#questionForm').submit(function() {
    if($('div.checkbox-group.required div :checkbox:checked').length > 0) {
        return true;//submit the form
    } else {
        return false; // do not submit the form
    }
});
```

Unfortunately there is no way to achieve what you are looking for  using **only html5**, whatever solution you choose it will probably have to be done with js.

Comment: Thanks, but like that the checkbox is not appearing properly the html is like "<div class="form-group"><label for="participant_question">Checkbox</label> <div class="checkbox-group required"> required&gt;   <div class="form-check"> <input type="checkbox" name="participant_question[]" value="check1" class="form-check-input"><label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">check1</label> </div>  <div class="form-check"> <input type="checkbox" name="participant_question[]" value="check2" class="form-check-input"><label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">check2</label> </div></div>

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]" value="1">  <input type="hidden" value="2" name="participant_question_id[]">  </div>".

Comment: It must be a typo because it's hard since I didn't code it on an IDE cant you check where it is?

Comment: Edited my post with my typo mistake solved I think, you could see that I was always putting  required and then the condition, the idea is that you need to do the same like what you are doing with select don't just copy paste mindlessly! xP

Comment: Edited again because I saw I did another 'typo' mistake X)

Comment: Thanks, if the checkbox is not checked and is required the form is not submitted but dont appears any validation message like "FIll this field" like it appears on the other fields. Do you know why? And also do you know how to, if the custom question is required add inside each question label this "<span class="text-primary">*</span>"?

Comment: And there is a issue, for example if the checkbox is not required, with this code "$('#registration_form').submit(function() {
                alert("'test");
                if($('div.checkbox-group.required div :checkbox:checked').length > 0) {
                    return true;//submit the form
                } else {
                    return false; // do not submit the form
                }
            });" the form is not submited, but if the checkbox is not required it should not return false.

Comment: I just showed you and explained why what you were asking wasn't do-able with html5 only, I showed you the way I'm not willing to code all your cases I just coded basic case you were asking for...

Comment: add inside each question label this "<span class="text-primary">*</span>" -> this can be easily done by adding a conditional statement inside your case in your controller

Comment: It should be in the RegistrationController or in the Question model?

Comment: Where you generate your html input on Question Model, when you insert the label you can use and if statement with $required variable like you have already done and if it's required append the <span class="text-primary">*</span>

Comment: Thanks, but the label is not in the Question model, it's in the registration.blade.php, so it should be like "                                        <label for="participant_question">{{$customQuestion->question}} <span class="text-primary">*</span></label>
", but like this it appears always if the input is required but also if its not required.

Comment: What I was refering when you use getInputHtml it could be there, personally I'm not a fan of how you are structuring your project but whatever

Comment: Thanks, I'm a beginner, maybe have the getHtmlInput in the model is not appropriate because a model is returning HTML but I don't know how to structure it more properly to achieve that context of generating custom fields with the correct type depending on what it's in the questions table type column.